# Проблема с установкой .Net Core для Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

Мне нужно установить .Net Core на Linux. Я изучил всю инструкцию по установке на сайте Microsoft, однако при команде wget https..., и так далее, выдает ошибку, что ссылка не найдена, однако именно та ссылка, что я использовал, была указана в инструкции. Есть другие способы по установке .Net Core?

Comment: Да, чё-то у них из папок все файлы делись. Или они переделывают структуру или сервак сдох. Наверное надо подождать.

Answer (score 0):

> Репозиторий packages.microsoft.com, через который для различных дистрибутивов Linux распространяются пакеты c продуктами Microsoft, в течение более чем 22 часов находился в неработоспособном состоянии. В том числе оказались недоступны для установки Linux-версии .NET Core, Microsoft Teams и Microsoft SQL Server, а также различные devops-обработчики Azure. Детали инцидента не раскрываются, упоминается лишь, что проблемы возникли из-за регрессивных изменений в процессе плановых работ.

https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=55361